# What does completing function do in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, transducer

I've came across `completing` function on [clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/completing) but there is no doc at the moment.

Could you provide some examples?

Comment: Have you checked its source: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6734 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`completing` is used to augment a binary reducing function that may not have a unary overload with a unary "completion" arity.

[The official transducers reference page](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) hosted @ [clojure.org](https://clojure.org/) explains the purpose of the nullary, unary and binary overloads of transducing functions and includes a good example of when the unary "completion" arity is useful in the section called "Creating Transducers" (the example used is `partition-all` which uses completion to produce the final block of output).

In short, the completion arity is used after all input is consumed and gives the transducing function the opportunity to perform any work to flush any buffers that the transducing process might maintain (as in the case of `partition-all`), apply any final transformations to the output (see below for an example of that) etc. Here by "transducing function" I mean the transducing function actually passed to `transduce` (or `eduction` or any similar function that sets up a transducing process) together with all the wrapping transducers.

For an interesting example of `completing` used with a non-trivial completion function, have a look at Christophe Grand's [xforms](https://github.com/cgrand/xforms): `net.cgrand.xforms.rfs/str` is a `transduce`-friendly version of `clojure.core/str` that will build up a string in linear time when used in a `transduce` call. (In contrast, `clojure.core/str`, if used in `reduce`/`transduce`, would create a new string at each step, and consequently run in O(n²) time.<sup>1</sup>) It uses `completing` to convert the `StringBuilder` that it uses under to hood to a string once it consumes all input. [Here's a stable link to its definition as of the current tip of the master branch.](https://github.com/cgrand/xforms/blob/81d0f0c1719a727e16d1820036d1741ec0bc1437/src/net/cgrand/xforms/rfs.cljc#L94)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note, however, that `clojure.core/str` runs in linear time if used with `apply` – it uses a `StringBuilder` under the hood just like `net.cgrand.xforms.rfs/str`. It's still convenient from time to time to have a `transduce`-friendly version (for use with transducers, or in higher-order contexts, or possibly for performance reasons when dealing with a large collection that can be reduced be efficiently than via `first`/`next` looping that `str` uses).